# php my admin do not start and display an alert message

Tags: compiler-errors, phpmyadmin, database-connection, wampserver

first i had the **WAMP server** installed but it did not turn to green just it turn for orange and stop working so i uninstall it and re install
after that it work fine but the **phpmyAdmin** system do not work as it should and display and error message :

****No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).**

can anyone help to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL server is probably not running. By the way, I have never seen phpMyAdmin displaying such a message.